# How can I display a text in an image on html using the event handler onclick

Tags: html, image, onclick, eventhandler

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <title>Squares</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function SayColor(color) {
          document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "You clicked on the " + color + " square!";
        }
        </script>
 </head>

  <body>

    <div style="text-align:center">
    <button onclick="SayColor()> <img src="red-square.png" height="150" width="150" ></button>
    <img src="green-square.png" height="150" width="150"> 
    <img src="blue-square.png" height="150" width="150"> 
    <h3 id="message">
    </h3>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my attempt at the beginning of the code, I'm not sure how to finish it. I'm familiar with event handlers but not functions. I am trying to display text in each image box when clicked that reads "You clicked on the [color of square] square!"

Comment: are you trying to do this after clicking the button with `SayColor()` function attached to it?

Comment: yes and I also tried having the onclick in the image tag; either I think would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I see you are defining the function but it requires some argument which you are not passing. And if you just need to click there is no button needed, like you can try like below, add event-handler for the image dom element itself. 
P.S you just cant pass it as red, since it will we undefined, so passing a string value here.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <title>Squares</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function SayColor(color) {
          document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "You clicked on the " + color + " square!";
        }
        </script>
 </head>

  <body>

    <div style="text-align:center">
     <img onclick=SayColor("RED") src="red-square.png" height="150" width="150" >
    <img onclick=SayColor("Green") src="green-square.png" height="150" width="150"> 
    <img onclick=SayColor("Blue") src="blue-square.png" height="150" width="150"> 
    <h3 id="message">
    </h3>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps! Happy coding!